# Diophantine equation for generating computably enumerable set

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

By Matiyasevich's theorem, each member of computably enumerable set can be obtain from a diophantine equation system. For prime numbers, this system of diophantine equation is found. My question is:

For special computably enumerable set as like as perfect numbers, how can we construct this diophantine equation system?

Is there Matiyasevich's type theorem for the matrix algebra?

Answer (score 6):

For Diophantine representations of perfect numbers, you may read V.Y. Kryauchyukas, *[Diophantine representation of perfect numbers](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01629440)*.

For James Jones' *Diophantine representations of Mersenne primes and Fermat primes*, see http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa35/aa3531.pdf

For universal Diophantine equation, please consult Jones' paper of that name in J. Symbolic Logic **47** (1982), 549–571, doi:[10.2307/2273588](https://doi.org/10.2307/2273588), also available from
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273588.

Jones' paper in 1982 contains a general method to transform any polynomial Diophantine equation over $\mathbb N=\{0,1,\ldots\}$ to one with at most 9 natural number unknowns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there such semi results for matrix algebra? For example, is there diophantine representation of all permutation matrices or determinant $\pm{1}$ matrices?